# Java: OOP advice and suggestion to advance a small app

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, collections, abstract

So this project is a little outside of my comfort zone.  I would describe my current stage of development as being one in which, “I know about things like: collection, design patters, and in general what makes for good OOP.  But these things are sort of at my current limits.  And so I probably don’t use them or attempt to use them as much as I should.”

I’m trying to change that, so I've been working on fairly small challenge/application that really lends itself to the above and asking myself to write smart, clean code.  I’m fairly happy with what I've been able to do so far.  However, I have two classes remaining that I still need to dive into.  I have a lot of ideas about how to go about this.  I’m sure some are good and some are bad, but more than anything, I think I’m over thinking things.

**In short, here is what I’m trying to do, here is what I have, and here is where I need to go:**

**What I’m trying to do:**  The simplest way to state the goals for this app are, I have credit card (this class is the class I have done), I have wallets, and I have people.  Looking at it from a high-level perspective, I’m putting cards in the wallets and wallets in the people.  I have 3 cards, they really only differ in their ‘names’ and interest rates.  I want some wallets to have 1 card and for others to have all three.  As for wallets clearly every person needs at least one, but I’d like to give someone two.  And that is really about it, I worked out some math for simple interest on the card which I’ll tie in at some point, but mostly I’m looking to build a clean and well-designed app.

**What I have:**  As I've stated I more or less have the `CreditCard` class done.  I’m still fine tuning it, but I've been able to improve it a lot and I’m casually happy with it.  I’ll include this class below to provide context for the app and also, so you can provide suggestions if needed.  At the top of the class you’ll see a lot of documentation.  This is mostly just the math, and it’s logic, for working out simple interest.  You’ll see. But I also have two test cases that I’m coding to, you’ll see this too.

**Where I need to go:**  Well I have credit cards.  Now I just need wallets and people.  From my perspective, I could see the wallet making use of an ArrayList.  Though, it could be the case that a different aspect of collections might serve better.  I have mostly(mostly) used ArrayList, and so I keep mostly using ArrayList.  It’s worked out so far…  Beyond that, I have been considering making Wallet and Person abstract, which seems like a good idea, but once again, not much experience in making these choices.

So at the end of all of this, I’m look for some direction, conformation of good ideas and alternatives to weaker ones.  If these could be combine with examples or if suggestions could express themselves in both words and code, this would be optimal because I get a lot more out of advice when I can see it in action.  For me an OK suggestion with code, is ‘generally’ more helpful than a great suggestion without.  It’s all about being able to apply that advice.  But, that’s just me and everyone is different.  What I can tell you, that is definite, is that all suggestion, whatever they are, will be appreciated and helpful.  Because, I’m doing this, I’m here, to learn.

```
/*
 * Test Cases:
 * 1) 1 person has 1 wallet and 3 cards (1 Visa, 1 MC 1 Discover) – Each     Card has a balance of $100 – calculate the total interest (simple interest) for this person and per card. 
 * 
 * 2) 1 person has 2 wallets  Wallet 1 has a Visa and Discover , wallet 2 a MC -  each card has $100 
 * balance - calculate the total interest(simple interest) for this person and interest per wallet
 */

/*
 * Formula Key:
 * 
 * Algebraic Symbols:
 * A = Total Accrued Amount (principal + interest)
 * P = Principal Amount
 * I = Interest Amount
 * r & R = Rate of Interest per year in percentage & decimal
 * t = Time Period involved in months or years(duration pertaining to this equation)
 * 
 * Rate of Interest, Percentage To Decimal Equations:
 *  R = r * 100
 *  r = R / 100
 * 
 * Simple Interest Equation:
 * A = P(1 + (r * t))
 */

/*
 * Card:
 * VISA 10%
 * 
 * Equation:
 * Accrued Amount(A) = Principle Amount(P) * (1 +(Interest Rate(r) * Time Period(t)))
 *
 * Calculation:
 * First, converting Interest Rate(R) of 10%, to, Interest Rate(r) of 0.1
 * r = R/100 = 10%/100 = 0.1 per year,
 * put Time Period(t) of 1 month into years,
 * months/year(1 month ÷ 12) = 0.08 years
 * 
 * Solving Equation:
 * A = 100(1 + (0.1 × 0.08)) = 100.8 
 * A = $ 100.80
 * 
 * Solution:
 * The total Amount Accrued(A), Principal(P) plus Interest(I),
 * from Simple Interest on a Principal(P) of $ 100.00
 * at a Rate(r = R/100(convert a percentage to a decimal)) of 10% or 0.1 per year
 * for 0.08 years, 1 month(t) is $ 100.80.
 */

/*
 * Card:
 * MC(Master Card) 5%
 * 
 * Equation:
 * Accrued Amount(A) = Principle Amount(P) * (1 +(Interest Rate(r) * Time Period(t)))
 * 
 * Calculation:
 * First, converting Interest Rate(R) of 5%, to, Interest Rate(r) of 0.05
 * r = R/100 = 5%/100 = 0.05 per year,
 * put Time Period(t) of 1 month into years,
 * months/year(1 month ÷ 12) = 0.08 years
 * 
 * Solving Equation:
 * A = 100(1 + (0.05 × 0.08)) = 100.4 
 * A = $ 100.40
 * 
 * Solution:
 * The total Amount Accrued(A), Principal(P) plus Interest(I),
 * from Simple Interest on a Principal(P) of $ 100.00
 * at a Rate(r = R/100(convert a percentage to a decimal)) of 5% or 0.05 per year
 * for 0.08 years, 1 month(t) is $ 100.40.
 */

/*
 * Card:
 * Discover 1%
 * 
 * Equation:
 * Accrued Amount(A) = Principle Amount(P) * (1 +(Interest Rate(r) * Time Period(t)))
 * 
 * Calculation:
 * First, converting Interest Rate(R) of 1%, to, Interest Rate(r) of 0.01
 * r = R/100 = 1%/100 = 0.01 per year,
 * put Time Period(t) into years,
 * months/year(1 month ÷ 12) = 0.08 years
 * 
 * 
 * Solving Equation:
 * A = 100(1 + (0.01 × 0.08)) = 100.08 
 * A = $ 100.08
 * 
 * Solution:
 * The total Amount Accrued(A), Principal(P) Plus Interest(I),
 * from Simple Interest on a Principal(P) of $ 100.00
 * at a Rate(r = R/100(convert a percentage to a decimal)) of 1% or 0.01 per year
 * for 0.08 years, 1 month(t) is $ 100.08.
 */

public class CreditCard 
{
    private BrandOfCard brandOfCard;
    private static final double PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT = 100.00;
    private static final double TIME_PERIOD = 0.08;

    public CreditCard(BrandOfCard brandOfCard) 
    {
        this.brandOfCard = brandOfCard;
    }

    /*
     * A = P(1 + (r * t))
     */
    public double getAccruedAmount() 
    {
        double accruedAmount;
        accruedAmount = PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT * (1 + (brandOfCard.getInterestRate() * TIME_PERIOD));
        return accruedAmount;
    }

    public enum BrandOfCard 
    {
        VISA(0.1), MASTER_CARD(0.05), DISCOVER(0.01);

        private final double interestRate;

        BrandOfCard(double interestRate) 
        {
            this.interestRate = interestRate;
        }

        public double getInterestRate() 
        {
            return interestRate;
        }
    }

    //bottom of class
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        CreditCard visa = new CreditCard(BrandOfCard.VISA);
        CreditCard masterCard = new CreditCard(BrandOfCard.MASTER_CARD);
        CreditCard discover = new CreditCard(BrandOfCard.DISCOVER);

        double accruedAmount;

        accruedAmount = visa.getAccruedAmount();
        System.out.println("Visa card, with a principle amount of $100.00, & an interest rate of 10%, " + 
                            "has accrued $" + (accruedAmount - PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT) + " in interest, " +
                            "over the last monthly term.");
        System.out.println("The total amount due on this card is now $" + accruedAmount);


        accruedAmount = masterCard.getAccruedAmount();
        System.out.println("Master Card card, with a principle amount of $100.00, & an interest rate of 5%, " + 
                            "has accrued $" + (accruedAmount - PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT) + " in interest, " +
                            "over the last monthly term.");
        System.out.println("The total amount due on this card is now $" + accruedAmount);

        accruedAmount = discover.getAccruedAmount();
        System.out.println("Discover card, with a principle amount of $100.00, & an interest rate of 1%, " + 
                "has accrued $" + (accruedAmount - PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT) + " in interest, " +
                "over the last monthly term.");
        System.out.println("The total amount due on this card is now $" + accruedAmount);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `Wallet`?

Comment: well, I guess firstly, it just seemed to make sense to me, in a "trying to get your code to better represent the lived world sort of way."  So it was from that, that I started trying to decide why a wallet is useful and what does it really do.  To bring that down to more of a code level, I would say that a wallet holds a group of like objects, in this case cards.  If a person were to have two wallets, the wallets hold objects and provide separation/difference between the two groups.  So that is what I would like to achieve in my wallets.

Comment: While this is true, the goal of OOP is not to implement every possible class in your design but only those that impact functionality.  How would card balance, interest, etc. depend on a particular wallet it's kept in?

Comment: Could not agree more.  Were these replies a bit longer, I would have gone on to say something very similar to what you have posted because, your post closely reflects a counter point I had been considering.  So clearly, I'm not an expert on OOP, but even in my modest study I've noticed many of these dualities in how OOP is taught, described, and used.  Probably the only true thing you could say about OOP, is OOP is as OOP dose. Which really gets back to the reason I asked this question, because in the absence of objectivity(no pun intended), gain perspective.

Comment: As for the wallet, in the matters of balance, interest, etc...it's not involved at all, it has no purpose.  However, I suppose its  useful to me in that it adds some new dynamics to my application, more practice. But functionally, not involved in the math.  Your observations and points are well taken,"What is the purpose of Wallet?" Damn good question, damn good...much better than this reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't go object happy!  More objects != better code!

Look at this from a data perspective because that is where most OOP programmers lose their way.  This stuff is stored relationally for a reason.

- People make that an object
- Wallet - This is simply a middle key to join n number of cards to a person.
- CC make that an object since each CC has defined terms of payment, fees, interest rates, etc.

What you end up with is:

- Table of users.
- Table of cards.

The wallet, unless you want to assign particular attributes to it is really a non existent thing, since having the card owner Key in the CC record links cards to owners.

The rub is really applying payments.  Just like the bank adds your deposits to your account **before** they start processing your checks or auto payments, you have to apply any posted payments before you calc the interest + fees value to add to the balance so:

```
for owners{
 for cards with card.ownerID = owners.ID{
   card.balance=card.balance-payments ;
   card.balance=card.balance+calcInterest(card.balance, card.rate)+GetSumOfFees(card);
   }
}
```

That is the basic batch job that every CC Issuer runs every night.

On the charging side of things it is the smallest code they can get away with sine this has to happen practically instantaneously at a pay terminal, etc. etc.

```
public static String chargeThis(String CCData, Double AMT){

     CCNum = GetCCNum(CCData) ;
     boolean isValid = validateCC(ccData);
     if(isValid) return chargeCC(ccNum,AMT) else return rejectedTrans ;
}
```

About lists hash maps, etc in Java or vectors in C++...

ANY operation on those that sizes them will be blazingly fast right up until the point they exceed the size of the L2 cache!  After they exceed the size of L2 cache they get stored in system RAM and their performance goes into the tank.  At this point a linked list is superior, since adding or subtracting an element is simply inserting a node, or deleting a node.

Remember, getting advanced performance requires understanding the machine AND understanding how the JVM or compiler arranges things.  In order from best to worst storage is as follows:

- L0 cache - 1 cpu cycle
- L1 cache - 2 cpu cycles
- L2 cache - 5 to 10 cpu cycles
- System Memory 1000's of cpu cycles
- Ethernet ( getting data across the wire ) 10's of K cycles
- Disk - 50 to 100 K cycles

Comment: negative one for missing the point. counting cycles keeps you on the way, when we oop-programmers writing two or three classes here?

Comment: @Aitch I don't even know what that comment means.  BTW I am an OOP programmer as well. Define the data FIRST, the objects second.

Comment: This is great!  This is what I'm talking about.  You suggest a map & instantly it strikes me as a great idea.  I just got done with a short review of maps and now I'm wondering why I haven't used them more often.  I think a big challenge for someone like myself(self-taught, no background, no resources beyond the net) when learn a massive language like Java, is simply the size of the language(not to mention additional languages and tech that can be used with) and the time it would take to explore it all.  Most people have background, training, or guidance to help them navigate,

Comment: @FlyingGuy I finished up the app.  You can email me at reedwilliams8404@gmail.com if you want to check it out and maybe give me suggestions.